# How to get the page ID from a public notion page url without querying a database

Tags: postman, notion-api

I would like to be able to receive a public Notion page URL and return the ID of that page. I don't know if that is possible using the API.

I've tried taking the end of this URL and using it to retrieve the page in postman
https://www.notion.so/asnunes/Simple-Page-Text-4d64bbc0634d4758befa85c5a3a6c22f

```
https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/4d64bbc0634d4758befa85c5a3a6c22f
```

But it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

The ID of the page is that alphanumeric string at the end of the URL before the query parameters. This would be what you would use when retrieving information from the page using the GET Page or GET block endpoints in the API.

If you do not have access to the page (i.e. your integration does not have access to the page in your workspace) you will not be able to use the API to make a request to it. You cannot use integrations to request information from other workspaces. Your integration is not authorized to access other workspaces.

Comment: I have given access to the page. Is it possible to check the pages what all pages were given approved ? Right now it seems unintuitive. I give access to the page during oauth but then again I should ask the user to insert the link to which page they gave access to it on the client side.